# Margin/offset problem with tabu

Tags: tables, margins, tabularx, tabu

I'm learning LaTeX and trying to create a sample resume. I've set the `margin=0in` but still, there is an offset in the first line and I'm not sure how to solve it?

[Link to Overleaf Code](https://www.overleaf.com/project/5f15471a16c3ee0001df7bd9)

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=0in,right=0in,top=0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabu}


\title{Resume}
\author{Firtname LastNamr}

%Fonts
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{SourceSansPro}[
Scale = 1.1,
Extension = .ttf,
UprightFont = *-Regular,
BoldFont = *-Bold,
]

\begin{document}
\begin{tabu} {X[l] X[r]}
\multirow{2}{\textwidth}{
FIRSTNAME LASTNAME
} & Contact: (+91) 123-456-8016\\
 & Email: abcdef@abc.ac.in, resumebuilder@gmail.com\\
\end{tabu}
\rule{\textwidth}{2.0pt}
\vspace{5pt}
\textbf{\large{EDUCATIONAL QUALIFICATIONS}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

From the image above we can see that `FIRST NAME` has an offset from the left, but it works fine for `EDUCATIONAL QUALIFICATIONS` and it has 0 margin. Also, it is perfectly fine on the right side with zero margin.

I'm trying to have a single cell(horizontal alingment=left, vertical alignment=center) in the first column and two cells(horizontal alingment=right, vertical alingment=center) in the second column(for contact and e-mail).

The `\rule{\textwidth}{2.0pt}` is also behaving weirdly. I want it to underline only the text and not extend beyond it.

Also, I'm totally confused about how to work with tables and alignments. `tabular, tabularx, tabu` are totally confusing with all the l,c,r,m,p... letters used for alignment.

Comment: Please keep in mind that `tabu` is [currently unmaintained](https://github.com/tabu-issues-for-future-maintainer/tabu) and might therefore contain some bugs that are not fixed. I'd currently recommend not using this package as there are other alternatives.

Comment: the table used in the first part has a column on the left with some thickness-- remove it with `@{}`

Comment: What exactly does `The \rule{\textwidth}{2.0pt} is also behaving weirdly. I want it to underline only the text and not extend beyond it.` mean? How would you like the rule to look like? What does "extand beyond it" mean here? Do you want two separate lines? One bwlos "first name last name" and a second below the contact information? Please clarify.

Comment: @leandriis I mean that the line should start exactly under the letter F of 'FIRST NAME' and end exactly under the last letter on the right side(under 'm')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your code compilable without any warnings, you will have to make some changes.

- Add `\noindent`immediately before the `tabu` environment and the `\rule` in order to remove part of the indentation.
- Add `@{}` before the first and after the last column specifier as in `{@{}X[l] X[r]@{}}` in order to remove the small horizontal white space that is automatically added left and right of the text in each table cell.
- Lasty, there is an uncommented linebreak within the `\multirow` command causing yet another little extra space.

With all the above mentioned changes you will arrive at something like:

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=0in,right=0in,top=0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabu}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabu} {@{}X[l] X[r]@{}}
\multirow{2}{=}{%
FIRSTNAME LASTNAME
} & Contact: (+91) 123-456-8016\\
 & Email: abcdef@abc.ac.in, resumebuilder@gmail.com\\
\end{tabu}
\noindent
\rule{\textwidth}{2.0pt}
\vspace{5pt}
\textbf{\large EDUCATIONAL QUALIFICATIONS}
\end{document}
```

---

As already mentioned in the comments, `tabu` is currently unmaintained and might contain some bugs that are currently not fixed. Therefore I would recomment using a different approach. The following MWE contains two alternative approaches using either `tabular*` or two side-by-side minipages resulting in a slightly different layout:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=0in,right=0in,top=0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{}l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r@{}}
\multirow{2}{*}{FIRSTNAME LASTNAME} & Contact: (+91) 123-456-8016\\
                                    & Email: abcdef@abc.ac.in, resumebuilder@gmail.com\\
\end{tabular*}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
  FIRSTNAME LASTNAME
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
  \raggedleft
  \begin{tabular}{ll@{}}
    Contact:& (+91) 123-456-8016\\                     
    Email:& abcdef@abc.ac.in, resumebuilder@gmail.com\\
  \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: what is the `=` for in `\multirow{2}{=}{%` ? Also, I'm unable to understand the use of `%`, what was the error ?

Comment: Regarding the `%` If you add a linebreak inside of the `\multirow` command, a space is added in the output. By commenting out the linebkreak through adding `%`there, you get rid of that space. Regarding the `=` in the `multirow` command: This ensures that the width of the multirow is equal to the width of the column it is used inside of.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to the table --rest no change

[image]

```
\begin{document}\noindent
\begin{tabu} {@{}X[l] X[r]}
```

**addendum -- for the rule**

[image]

change the following--

```
\begin{document}\noindent
\begin{tabu} {@{}X[l] X[r]}
\multirow{2}{\textwidth}{FIRSTNAME LASTNAME} & Contact: (+91) 123-456-8016\\
                                            & Email: abcdef@abc.ac.in, resumebuilder@gmail.com\\
\end{tabu}
\noindent\rule{0.4\textwidth}{2pt}\par 
\vspace{5pt}
\noindent\textbf{\large{EDUCATIONAL QUALIFICATIONS}}
\end{document}
```